# Index is out of bounds with axis? What does that mean?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have this code that takes my arrays, x1,y1,z1, vx1, vy1,vz1, and operates on them (this is the bulk of the code), and at the end I'm left with new arrays x2,y2,z2, vx2,vy2,vz2. What I want to do is  the whole code, updating x1 with x2, y1 with y2, and so on....
However, when I set x1=x2... at the end of my code, I get this error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "myfile.py", line 33, in <module>

      File "myfile.py", line 30, in do_work
        M[xn,step] = ((mass1[xn]*mass1[step+1]*((x1[step+1]**2.+y1[step+1]**2.+z1[step+1]**2.)-(x1[xn]**2.+y1[xn]**2.+z1[xn]**2.)))/  (abs((x1[step+1]**2.+y1[step+1]**2.+z1[step+1]**2.)-(x1[xn]**2.+y1[xn]**2.+z1[xn]**2.))**2.+(.2)**2  )**(3))

    IndexError: index 999 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 999
```

and I cannot figure out why. I don't understand why my code won't work for my new arrays x2,y2,z2,... etc. (I know my function is kind of a mess, but I'm afraid the problem might be in there and so that's why I'm posting it as-is)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import itertools
start_time = time.time()


G=1
dt=.01

n1 = np.loadtxt('homo_sph_N1000_R3_v1.dat',usecols=(0),skiprows=0)
mass1= np.loadtxt('homo_sph_N1000_R3_v1.dat',usecols=(1),skiprows=0)
x1=np.loadtxt('homo_sph_N1000_R3_v1.dat',usecols=(2),skiprows=0)
y1=np.loadtxt('homo_sph_N1000_R3_v1.dat',usecols=(3),skiprows=0)
z1=np.loadtxt('homo_sph_N1000_R3_v1.dat',usecols=(4),skiprows=0)
vx1=np.loadtxt('homo_sph_N1000_R3_v1.dat',usecols=(5),skiprows=0)
vy1=np.loadtxt('homo_sph_N1000_R3_v1.dat',usecols=(6),skiprows=0)
vz1=np.loadtxt('homo_sph_N1000_R3_v1.dat',usecols=(7),skiprows=0)

npoints=len(n1)-1

M = np.zeros((npoints,npoints))

for timestep in xrange(0,2):

     def do_work(xn, step):

         #This is where I begin operating on intial arrays
         M[xn,step] = ((mass1[xn]*mass1[step+1]*((x1[step+1]**2.+y1[step+1]**2.+z1[step+1]**2.)-(x1[xn]**2.+y1[xn]**2.+z1[xn]**2.)))/  (abs((x1[step+1]**2.+y1[step+1]**2.+z1[step+1]**2.)-(x1[xn]**2.+y1[xn]**2.+z1[xn]**2.))**2.+(.2)**2  )**(3))

     [do_work(xn, step) for (xn,step) in itertools.product(xrange(0,npoints), xrange(0,npoints))]


     a=[np.sum(arr) for arr in M]


     a = np.array(a)
     vxx = np.array(vx1)
     vyy=np.array(vy1)
     vzz=np.array(vz1)
     vx=vxx[0:npoints]
     vy=vyy[0:npoints]
     vz=vzz[0:npoints]


     vx2 = vx + (a +a)/2  * dt
     vy2 = vy + (a +a)/2  * dt
     vz2 = vz + (a+a)/2   * dt

     xx = np.array(x1)
     yy = np.array(y1)
     zz = np.array(z1)

     x=xx[0:npoints]
     y=yy[0:npoints]
     z=zz[0:npoints]

#x2,y2,z2.... are new arrays
     x2= np.array((x+vx2*dt) + (a*dt**2)/2)
     y2= np.array((y+vy2*dt) + (a*dt**2)/2)
     z2= np.array((z+vz2*dt) + (a*dt**2)/2)


  #I set x1....=x2... so this whole thing will loop using the new array values 
     x1=x2
     y1=y2
     z1=z2
```

Comment: For an array with shape (999,), valid indexes range from 0 to 998, but do not include 999.  Python indexing is 0 based.  `axis 0` refers to the only dimension of 1d array, and the first dimension of multi-dimensional array.  Evidently you are indexing over an invalid range in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subtract 1 from npoints

```
[do_work(xn, step) for (xn,step) in itertools.product(xrange(0,npoints-1), xrange(0,npoints-1))]
```